# Inverse relationship mapping based on "one to many" using Entity Framework and GraphQl

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, graphql, entity-relationship, inverse-relationship

I'm working on a new version of my API, now using GraphQL for some advantages.

I have the entity `Partner` which has a `List` property of `Farm`s. On that point is ok, when I call `Partners` on my API I can get their `Farms`.

But when I call `Farms` in my API, I want it to return the `Partner` related to it, and there is my issue.

I tried using `InverseProperty` annotation on `Partner` beyond `ForeignKey` on `Farm`, but I get the following error message for every attibute of `Farm`:

> Expected to find property *[attribute]* on Int32 but it does not exist.

Here is part of my code:

```
public class Partner 
{
    ...
    [InverseProperty("PartnerOwner")]
    public List<Farm> Farms{ get; set; }
}

public class Farm 
{
    ...
    [Key]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PartnerOwner")]
    public int Partner { get; set; }

    public Partner PartnerOwner { get; set; }
}
```

Schema:

```
type Propriedade 
{
    Codigo: ID,
    ...
    Parceiro: Parceiro
}

type Partner 
{
    Codigo: ID,
    ...
    CountryFarms: [Farm]
}
```

Is there some detail I'm missing on that development?

It's a legacy code, because of that it doesn't follow code conventions neither I can change `Partner` property of `Farm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution while posting the doubt (like Rubber Duck Debugging).

On Schema, the **attributes names** must be the same of the class (seems obvious, I know, but take care). On this case specifically the Schema seems like this to work fine:

```
type Propriedade {
                    Codigo: ID,
                    ...
                    Parceiro: Parceiro
                }

type Partner {
                    Codigo: ID,
                    ...
                    // Here is the trick
                    Farms: [Farm]
                }
```